How to determine , by mental arithmetic, the cube root of 188,132,517 is 573? Question is from Hua LooKeng.
From an article by Chinese mathematician LooKeng-Hua:
"Someone can blurt out that the cube root of 188,132,517 is 573. Of course, 188 determines the first digit 5, and the last digit 7 determines the 3, but the reader might wonder, how is the middle 7 calculated?
It can be seen that there are two methods: one from the beginning to the end, and one from the end to the beginning."
I cannot understand what is the method to calculate the middle digit 7 by mental arithmetic.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Arguing modulo 3 shows that the middle digit is 1, 4 or 7.

Historical context (problem given to mental calculator Devi): search for 188 here $\ \ $

I wander how one can even determine it is an integer?

sorry，Supplement: we agree that the answers to the root are all integers

Cast elevens $\Rightarrow\bmod 11\!:\ \color{#0a0}{188132517\equiv 1}\equiv (\color{#c00}{503}\!+\!10t)^3\equiv (\color{#c00}8\!-\!t)^3\,$ so $\,8\!-\!t\equiv \color{#0a0}1\,$ so $\,t\equiv 7\ \ $

by $,\color{#0a0}{188132517}\equiv 1!-!8!+!8!-!1!+!3!-!2!+!5!-!1!+!7\equiv \color{#0a0}1,,\ \color{#c00}{503}\equiv 5!-!0!+!3\equiv \color{#c00}8\pmod{!11}\ \ $

Please strive not to answer PSQs.

@Sahaj Showing working is not the only way to demonstrate context. The source and the motivation for this question are perfectly clear.

$!!\bmod 11!:\ \color{#c00}{x^3}\equiv\color{#0a0} 1\Rightarrow x\equiv \color{#0a0}1,$ by $,x\equiv{x^{10}/(\color{#c00}{x^3})^3}!\equiv 1/\color{#c00}1^3.,$ Or by $:!\color{#c00}{3}$'rd roots unique, by $,\gcd(\color{#c00}3,\underbrace{\phi(11)}_{\large 10})!=!1.,$

@TobyM  There is nothing in the question save for a quote, and a plea close to "I have no clue. Help me". zero context.  Sahaj was spot on in his reminder to a user who barks the same to countless answerers.

<< Too long for comment >>
When we learn (memorize) the multiplication table in school , we are targeting mental arithmetic. That gets extended to this type of advanced calculations , which naturally requires advanced memorization.
When we know what we have is $(500+10X+3)^3$ , we will use the memorized values for :
$503^3=\color{gray}{127263527}$
$(500+10X+3)^3=1000 X^3 + \color{violet}{150900} X^2 + \color{violet}{7590270} X + 127263527$ (just like the multiplication table , the Sum of the two numbers highlighted might be required to be memorized too)
It is then just a matter of guesstimating $[188132517-\color{gray}{127263527}]/[\color{violet}{150900}+\color{violet}{7590270}]=60868990/7741170 \approx 609/77 \approx 7.91$
<< Middle Digit is $7$ >>
ADDENDUM :
There is no "one over-all method" to make such calculations.
Each Case & Each "Expert" will have a Set of techniques. I have high-lighted just one technique here.
